# jQuery object literal or module pattern with jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, jquery-plugins

Let's say we have something like this with the jQuery select2 plugin:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.select2').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: true,
      url: getUrl,
      data: getData,
      processResults: getProcessResults
    }
  });

  function getUrl() {
    return 'http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4JZYSpOHM';
  }

  function getData(params) {
    return {
      q: params.term
    };
  }

  function getProcessResults(data) {
    return {
      results: data
    };
  }

});
```

```css
.select2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="select2"></select>
```

But we wanna use an object literal or the module pattern for the jQuery feature and plugin like this:

```js
var myAjax = {

  init: function() {
    var _this = this;

    $('.select2').select2({
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        url: _this.getUrl,
        data: _this.getData,
        processResults: _this.getProcessResults
      }
    });
  },

  getUrl: function() {
    return 'http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4JZYSpOHM';
  },

  getData: function(params) {
    return {
      q: params.term
    };
  },

  getProcessResults: function(data) {
    return {
      results: data
    };
  }
  
};

$(document).ready(myAjax.init);
```

```css
.select2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="select2"></select>
```

How can we do that?

Sources:

https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that `this` within the `init` function will refer to the `document`, as you run it under the document.ready handler. To fix this you can use the `myAjax` variable directly to call its properties and methods. Try this:

```js
var myAjax = {
  init: function() {    
    $('.select2').select2({
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        url: myAjax.getUrl(),
        data: myAjax.getData,
        processResults: myAjax.getProcessResults
      }
    });
  },
  getUrl: function() {
    return 'http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4JZYSpOHM';
  },
  getData: function(params) {
    return {
      q: params.term
    };
  },
  getProcessResults: function(data) {
    return {
      results: data
    };
  }
};

$(document).ready(myAjax.init);
```

```css
.select2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<select class="select2"></select>
```

I'd also suggest you change the name of the object as `myAjax` isn't very semantic given its purpose.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I have edited the examples. See above.

Comment: If I add (). I get: "message": "Uncaught TypeError: _this.getUrl is not a function"

Comment: You're right - my mistake. I've corrected the answer for you. The problem is with the scope of `this`, so you need to use `myAjax` directly when dealing with its properties and methods.